# Upload a file to Google Drive using Google Sign In from Android device

Tags: android, google-drive-api, access-token, google-signin, drive

I am trying to build an standalone app to upload a file from my Android device to Google Drive. I am trying to integrate Google Sign-In for the same. I have followed the steps in the following link:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

After sign in is successful, I am unclear about the steps to upload a file from device. Can anyone please guide me with the steps with an example?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> As Drive Android API is deprecated as of December 6, 2018 and will be turned down on December 6, 2019 so apps must migrate to the Drive REST API or another suitable solution to avoid disruptions.

Google has provided sample apps on how to use the drive API  which you can find [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/master/drive/deprecation/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/driveapimigration/DriveServiceHelper.java).